# Linux bash - Input format

Tags: linux, bash, input, format

I have this standard input:

```
read -p "Server-Number: " servernumber
```

The Server numbers goes from 01 - 99
It is important, that the number has a zero (01, 02, 03, ..., 10, 11, ..., 99)
How can I edit the variable, if the number is only 1 instead of 01 ?

Sorry for my bad english ;)
I hope your understand my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
servernumber=`printf %02d $servernumber`
```

Comment: Assuming you are using `bash` 4 or later: `printf -v servernumber "%02d" "$servernumber"`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash only, no other processes:

```
servernumber=0$servernumber         # add leading 0
servernumber=${servernumber: -2}    # take last 2 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

write an if condition for checking the value of

```
echo $servernumber | nawk '/0/{print NR}' == 1
```